# ListView not "refreshing" after item is deleted from it

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-listview, adapter

I am trying to figure out how I "Refresh" the list view the user is on when an item from my listview is deleted. I have tried notifyDataSetChanged() but to no avail, which is puzzling to me because this works when I add an item.

P.S. I know the item is getting deleted because if I press the back button and get to my activity again, the item is removed from the listview visually.

```
    public void deleteButtonClicked(View view){
    dbHandler.deleteExerciseFromDatabase(exerciseClickedbyUser, workoutClicked);
    exerciseListView.setAdapter(edsAdapter);
    edsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Exercise Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

When I run this in the emulator, the Toast does appear.

public class CustomExerciseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

```
public CustomExerciseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> workouts) {
    super(context, R.layout.exercise_custom_row, workouts);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exercise_custom_row, parent, false);

    String singleExerciseItem = getItem(position);
    TextView exerciseTV = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.exerciseTV);
    exerciseTV.setText(singleExerciseItem);

    return customView;
}
```

Here is my class that contains deleteButtonClicked

```
public class ExercisesSection extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText userWorkoutInput;
private Button addNewWorkoutButton;
private CustomExerciseAdapter edsAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> itemHold;
private MyDBHandler dbHandler;
private String workoutClicked;
private String exerciseClickedbyUser;
private ListView exerciseListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercises_section);

    initViews();
    handleIntentData();
    inputTextHandler();
    loadDataFromDatabase();


}
//This method initializes all the views
public void initViews(){
    userWorkoutInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userWorkoutInput);
    addNewWorkoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNewWorkoutButton);
    exerciseListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exerciseListView);
    itemHold = new ArrayList<String>();
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this,null,null,1);
}

//This method makes the "Add new workout Button" clickable or not depending on user input
public void inputTextHandler(){

    userWorkoutInput.addTextChangedListener(
            new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    boolean isEmpty = false;
                    if ((userWorkoutInput.getText().toString().trim()).equals("")) {
                        isEmpty = true;
                    }
                    addNewWorkoutButton.setEnabled(!isEmpty);
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            }
    );
}

/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
THIS IS THE BUTTON LISTENER FOR @id+/addNewWorkoutButton
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
public void addWorkoutButtonClicked(View view){
    String input = (userWorkoutInput.getText().toString().trim());
    if (!input.equals("")){
        addItemToList(input);
        userWorkoutInput.setText("");   //Empties the edit text section
        saveDataToDatabase(input);
    }
}

public void saveDataToDatabase(String input){
    //GIVE THE EXERCISES OBJ VALUES!
    Exercises exercises = new Exercises(input, workoutClicked);
    dbHandler.addExerciseToDatabase(exercises);
}

public void loadDataFromDatabase(){

    String exerName = dbHandler.getExercisesForBodyParts(workoutClicked);

    //IF STATEMENT WEEDS OUT EMPTY DATA
    if(!(exerName.trim().equals(""))) {
        String delim = ",";
        String[] tokens = exerName.split(delim);
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            addItemToList(tokens[i]);
        }
    }
}

public void addItemToList(String input){

    itemHold.add(input);
    edsAdapter = new CustomExerciseAdapter(this, itemHold);

    exerciseListView.setAdapter(edsAdapter);
    edsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    exerciseListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    exerciseClickedbyUser = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    textClicked(view, exerciseClickedbyUser);  //starts intent and sends to Exercise Clicked Activity
                }
            }
    );

}

/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 This method is an onClick Method from exercise_custom_row.xml
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/

public void deleteButtonClicked(View view){
    dbHandler.deleteExerciseFromDatabase(exerciseClickedbyUser, workoutClicked);
    itemHold.remove(exerciseClickedbyUser);

    edsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Exercise Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 This method gets the data (name of section clicked) from MainActivity
 and changes the textView in exercise_section accordingly
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
public void handleIntentData(){

    Bundle workoutData = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (workoutData == null){
        return;
    }

    workoutClicked = workoutData.getString("exerciseChosen");
    TextView exerciseChosenText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exerciseChosenText);
    exerciseChosenText.setText(workoutClicked);
    exerciseChosenText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
}



public void textClicked(View view, String exercise){

    Intent i = new Intent(this, ExerciseClicked.class);
    i.putExtra("exerciseClicked", exercise);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Comment: Why do you set the Adapter  (with setAdapter method) in the onClick?

Comment: Post your Adapter. Is it getting it's data directly from the database?

Comment: It makes no sense to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after reloading the Adapter... Are you reloading it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys, but in the end the answer I came up with is quite different from yours. I ended up using his method   [1]: http://jmsliu.com/2444/click-button-in-listview-and-get-item-position.html/ "here" which worked absolutely perfect for me. Anyways this was what did for those who might run into the same issue.

**STICK THIS CODE IN THE GetView() method LOCATED IN .JAVA FILE INFLATES THE XML FILE.**

```
Button deleteButton = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
deleteButton.setTag(position);
```

**Then add this into your button click listener/ onClick method**

```
    int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
    list.remove(position);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my app, I don't use `notifyDataSetChanged` at all. To refresh the ListView, I simply **run the database query again** and use [`CursorAdapter.changeCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor(android.database.Cursor)). It will automatically call `notifyDataSetChanged` as needed.

Comment: Sorry this might be a dumb question, but where do you use the CursorAdapter.chageCursor ?

Comment: [In the method I wrote to refresh the ListView, after the database query.](https://github.com/nkorth/AndroidNotepad/blob/master/src/com/nkorth/notepad/TextListFragment.java#L183-L189)

Answer (score 1):

Your item is being deleted from database but the listview is not updating visually.Setting adapter is a solution but it will reset the list from start which not make a good experience for user to scroll all the time again.You can do one thing when you removing item from database at the same time you can remove selected item from your list. I think your listview listener should look like this in your activity:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                deleteButtonClicked(postion);
            }
        });



public void deleteButtonClicked(int position){
           int count=dbHandler.deleteExerciseFromDatabase(exerciseClickedbyUser, workoutClicked);
    if(count>0){
        list.remove(position);

            edsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Exercise Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sorry this might be a dumb question but i am very new to this (started 3 days ago). I seem to be having a difficulty with list.remove(position). Where are you getting this position variable from?

Comment: I did, by the way instead of using position i passed in the string I want to delete from the list however It still does not seem to be working. Here is what I changed 
        `dbHandler.deleteExerciseFromDatabase(exerciseClickedbyUser, workoutClicked);
        itemHold.remove(exerciseClickedbyUser);
        edsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Have you checked my eddited answer ? Please do like this.

Comment: I did try the edited answer but it seems to be giving me 'cannot resolve symnbol' errors on setOnItemClickListener

Comment: Bro you have to use your listview instance and then have to set listener on this.

Comment: Do you think that you could look at the code above where the deleteButtonClicked method located. I have tried you code again but it seems to not like the variable position, the error 'cannot resolve position' appears.

Answer (score 1):

You can perfectly remove item from adapter by using following code.

```
mCollection.remove(position);
mListLayout.removeAllViews();
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem no change in listview because your ArrayList or Array you assigned to the adapter has no changes. Please remove the item from the ArrayList or array too. And you just have to call notifyDataSetChanged() ., ie, there is no need of calling listview.setAdapter(adapter) again.

**EDIT :**

please replace your customArrayAdapter with the below shown code

```
   private  ArrayList<String> workouts;

    public CustomExerciseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> workouts) {
        super(context, R.layout.exercise_custom_row, workouts);
        this.workouts = workouts;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exercise_custom_row, parent, false);
                /////here change to 
        String singleExerciseItem = (String)workouts.get(position);
        TextView exerciseTV = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.exerciseTV);
        exerciseTV.setText(singleExerciseItem);

        return customView;
    }


    public void setList(ArrayList<String> workouts){

       this.workouts = workouts;
       notifyDatasetChanged();

    }
}
```

In your delete method, after updating database and your list, call adapter.setList(workouts),. it may do the trick for you.

Comment: Hi @Ansal Ali, I added the following         itemHold.remove(exerciseClickedbyUser);
        edsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but i seem to be getting the same results. Is there something else I'm missing out on

Comment: removing edsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); from will not have any effect on your listview. check it and confirm please.

Comment: if by not have any effect meaning the view remains the same and "un refreshed" then yes, there is no effect

Comment: And you removing a row from the parent activity not from the adapter...right??

Comment: after adding an item, do you need to call notifyDatasetChanged().?

Comment: And how did you invoke that deleteButtonClicked() method? some times screenshots of your activity with markings can be very useful.

Comment: I just tried adding an item and it works without calling notifyDatasetChanged(), sorry

Comment: after adding an item, REMOVE  exerciseListView.setAdapter(edsAdapter); and put only edsAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();.  And check whether still it works fine

Comment: K. done. I will edit my answer soon. please stay tuned...:-)

Comment: I have edited my answer.. please let me know your results

Comment: thanks for all your help! but I found another solution that fits the bill

Answer (score 0):

after removing items always add the below two lines

```
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

notifydatasetchanged will see for any changes in the list 
and notifydatasetinvalidated will check if there is any item removed then it will update the list